# devise destroy_user_session_path dont work on digitalocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, digital-ocean

I have sample rails application which has devise authentication.
I have deployed the application in a digital ocean droplet.In production user can sign in successfully but the user cannot sign out.
I have a java script error in my console which says,

```
Uncaught TypeError: ht.each is not a function
at application-4704efeb2d5b3aaf28f84af8b35e95edffed681c04b55448913ecd871f7f7ba0.js:1
at application-4704efeb2d5b3aaf28f84af8b35e95edffed681c04b55448913ecd871f7f7ba0.js:1
at application-4704efeb2d5b3aaf28f84af8b35e95edffed681c04b55448913ecd871f7f7ba0.js:1
```

How to overcome this situation?

Comment: search your code for `ht.each` and maybe post it?

Comment: i don't have a code like that in my application

Comment: Its prob somewhere in the js. What you could do is open the current application-xxx.js in chrome dev tools source panel. Since its line 1 I assume that its minified but there is a little button with `{}` on it so you can prettify it. Search there for `ht.each`. So you narrow it down where it comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run this locally, it may help you identify the problem.

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

If that doesn't throw any errors, then you need to post what javascripts are loaded in your application.js file.

Comment: i found the actual problem, this was caused by the ducktap gem , i scoped it to development, thank you!